# How to change the paragraph spacing in Typst?

Tags: spacing, paragraph, typst

How to change the paragraph spacing in Typst? Do we have any codes to perform it? It seems the function par() is not the case.......

I tried to look for the relevant codes, but I failed to find them. Any suggestions, mates?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the spacing between paragraphs, or lines in the paragraph?

`leading` controls the spacing between lines:

```
#set par(leading: 2em)
#lorem(100)
```

[image]

A block's `spacing` controls the distance between paragraphs:

```
#set block(spacing: 4em)
#lorem(30)

#lorem(30)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, the spacing between paragraphs was exactly what I wanted to ask.